# if you have a DLL creating a bitmap in memory, how to return it to the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a DLL that is going to return an object(bitmap) and I have to pass it to the browser.

All in memory, no disk access.

I know how to do it with asp.net webform but I have no clue with MVC.

with webform,

since I have control over the dll, I inherit the class with the webcontrol.image.

in the aspx page I create a simple img link like:

```
   <img src="Handler1.ashx>
```

in the Handler1.ashx I have code like:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    context.Response.Clear()
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing
    Dim dll As New myDll.Class

    dll.drawPicture(bmp)

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    bmp.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    context.Response.End()
End Sub
```

(I removed the cleaning stuff/useless code to keep it short)

***edit***

solution is

```
Function img() As FileResult
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing
    Dim dll As New myDll.myClass
    dll.DrawPicture(bmp)

    Dim imgStream As New IO.MemoryStream
    bmp.Save(imgStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    imgStream.Position = 0

    bmp.Dispose()
    dll.Dispose()
    bmp = Nothing
    dll = Nothing

    Return File(imgStream.ToArray, "image/png")
End Function
```

I have no problem running cleaning code on everything except the memorystream, is there a chance for a memoryleak there? (I think yes)

Comment: Could you post the code you use with WebForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use controller action which returns [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) with [Controller.File()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) method.

Comment: very nice solution:  gives you a controller method you can unit test.

Comment: still have a question about memory leak, if you know

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic handler and save the bitmap (.Save) with Response.OutputStream

Comment: So it would be the same as webform?