# Showing runtime genrated Image in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to show runtime generated image on a View in ASP.NET MVC web application. 
How can I render this image - should I use an .aspx or .ashx file?

Comment: You've got a full answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image

Comment: Also, I'd suggest not using the file system as an intermediary; pick one of the solutions that returns a stream and just send the backing stream that contains your image down the wire.

Answer (score 0):

create a bitmap object

create a graphic object based on the bitmap

use the drawstring function from the graphic object

when your done, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964741/if-you-have-a-dll-creating-a-bitmap-in-memory-how-to-return-it-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you choose between aspx and ashx - ashx is the better because they are lighter. In ASP.NET MVC you can also create your own [ImageResult](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx) and use Controller's action to render images. You can use GDI++ to generate the images. If you need transparent images I suggest you save all images as .png files because the quallity of GDI++ generated .png-s is better than any other format.